# DOS stub in a PE file

Tags: windows, exe, dos, portable-executable

Lately, I analyzed some Windows executable files using a hex editor. The PE header starts at address 0x100, so there are 256 Bytes of data before the PE image actually starts. The first 256 Bytes:

[image: First 256 Bytes of a Windows executable]

I know the following about the file structure

- 0x00 - 0x3F: This is the MZ header (64 bytes long).
- 0x40 - 0x4D: These 14 bytes encode seven x86 (16 bit mode) instructions, which are used to print "This program cannot run in DOS mode.\r\r\n" to the screen, using a DOS system call (interrupt 0x21).
- 0x4E - 0x78: This is the string "This program cannot run in DOS mode.\r\r\n" with a dollar-sign at the end, which tells DOS that this is the end of the string.
- 0x79 - 0x7F: These are NULL bytes; I guess that they are inserted for alignment.

So I know what the first 128 bytes are for. My question is: What are the next 128 bytes (0x80 - 0xFF) used for? (The PE image starts after them at 0x100.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the so-called undocumented ["Rich header"](http://bytepointer.com/articles/the_microsoft_rich_header.htm).  It's a weakly encrypted block of data inserted by the Microsoft linker that indicates what Microsoft tools were used to make the executable. It includes version information from the object files linked, so includes information on what compilers, assemblers and other tools were used.

To decode the Rich header search for the `Rich` marker and then obtain the 32-bit encryption key that follows.  Then working backwards from the `Rich` marker, XOR the key with the 32-bit values stored there until you find a decoded `DanS` marker.  In between these two markers will be a list of pairs of 32-bit values. The first value of the pair identifies the Microsoft tool used, and the second value indicates how many linked object files were created using this tool.  The upper 16-bit part of the tool id value indicates what kind of tool it was, and the lower 16-bit part identifies the build version of the tool.

Comment: This was exactly the information I was looking for, and the link you provided is also very helpful. Thank you very much!